# How to make scrbook work well with letter sized paper?

Tags: koma-script

I tried using KOMA Script's `scrbook` with letter sized paper and got what to me seems strangely proportioned margins:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-10] % chktex 8
\end{document}
```

[image]

That bottom margin is massive and quite wasteful on paper, with the text hardly using half of the page. The A4 variant of this document doesn't look nearly as strange. Is this normal? Is there a generally-accepted configuration to make `scrbook` look better with letter sized paper?

Comment: What, you don't find KOMA margins aesthetically pleasing?  Inconceivable!  Seriously, just use geometry.sty and ignore KOMAs feeble attempts at artistic superiority.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, seriously, I didn't know this was a commonly understood sentiment about KOMA Script!

Comment: @ana After ten years here: some folks here don't like KOMA-script, but mostly out of lack of knowledge about typography. 'texdoc scrguien' provides the manual and you'll find the section about margin and papersize right at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no `DIV` value given for page sizes other than A4, KOMA-Script uses a DIV calculation for good line width. You can find the calculated `DIV` value in the log file:  with your example it is `DIV=7`.

If you want to decrease the margins, enlarge `DIV` manually. You can use eg. `DIV=10` or `DIV=11` in the class options.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,DIV=11]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]